# Why does `set nocompatible` result in vim saving extra, all-numeric temporary files?

Tags: save, linux, swap-file

I've narrowed down a bug in a program I'm working on to (surprisingly) some vim behavior!

The program contains a file watcher.
When I write a file with `vim -u NONE` and all the default settings, the behavior is as expected: some swap files are created and deleted, and the main file is saved.

But when I add `:set nocompatible`, I get the following additional inotify events:

```
wd=149, mask=IN_CREATE (0x100), cookie=0, length=16, name='4913'
wd=149, mask=IN_ATTRIB (0x4), cookie=0, length=16, name='4913'
wd=149, mask=IN_DELETE (0x200), cookie=0, length=16, name='4913'
<normal events appear after>
```

This indicates that vim is creating, modifying, and then deleting a file called `4913` in the directory of the file I'm editing.

If I create such a file myself (and `chmod 000` it), vim will use `5036` instead.
This leads me to believe that vim is looking for some arbitrary temporary file.

The number is always `4913` (across files, across reboots).

This is quite alarming.
I obviously want to use `nocompatible`, but this is a prohibitive bug.
What can I do?

Comment: Why is this a bug? Rethink your file watcher to allow other programs to do their job as they can. Vim isn't doing something forbidden.

Comment: @VanLaser: Yep, I've since added exceptions for `4913` and friends. The bug is that the file is called `4913` instead of `.vim_permissions_test`. I'm certain that I'm not the first person confused by such a filename. Just because it's not forbidden doesn't mean it's not unwise.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to say that it's not clear what your program / file watcher is doing, and why the fact that another program (i.e. vim) creates some temporary files would be "alarming" and "a prohibitive bug". Is your program actually a vim plugin? (this isn't something important, just unclear)

Answer (score 6):

When writing a buffer Vim will create a temporary file which it will `fchown()` to verify it has permission to create files in this directory; simplified version from `buf_write()` in `src/fileio.c`:

```
/*
 * Check if we can create a file and set the owner/group to
 * the ones from the original file.
 * First find a file name that doesn't exist yet (use some
 * arbitrary numbers).
 */
STRCPY(IObuff, fname);
for (i = 4913; ; i += 123)
{
    sprintf((char *)gettail(IObuff), "%d", i);
    if (mch_lstat((char *)IObuff, &st) < 0)
        break;
}
fd = mch_open((char *)IObuff,
                    O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_EXCL|O_NOFOLLOW, perm);
if (fd < 0)     /* can't write in directory */
    backup_copy = TRUE;
else
{

    ignored = fchown(fd, st_old.st_uid, st_old.st_gid);
    if (mch_stat((char *)IObuff, &st) < 0
            || st.st_uid != st_old.st_uid
            || st.st_gid != st_old.st_gid
            || (long)st.st_mode != perm)
        backup_copy = TRUE;
    /* Close the file before removing it, on MS-Windows we
     * can't delete an open file. */
    close(fd);
    mch_remove(IObuff);
```

So it will first try `4913`, and it will keep increment it with `123` until we find a filename that doesn't exist yet. Why `4913` and not `4912` or `4914`? I have no idea. It could be that the number is truly arbitrary.

This code is only run if the [`'backupcopy'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27backupcopy%27) setting is set to `auto`; from the help page:

```
The main values are:
"yes"   make a copy of the file and overwrite the original one
"no"    rename the file and write a new one
"auto"  one of the previous, what works best
```

It's used to help determine which value to use (hence the setting of `backup_copy = TRUE` in the above code).

The "compatible" vi default for `backupcopy` is `yes`, while the "non-compatible" Vim default is `auto`; when setting `compatible` Vim will reset various settings back to the Vi or Vim defaults:

```
:set compatible
:set backupcopy?
  backupcopy=yes

:set nocompatible
:set backupcopy?
  backupcopy=auto
```